# Programmatically creating embeddable links to excel files on business one drive

Tags: r, excel, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create an embed link to excel files on my business one drive account. I'm doing so programmatically and there are a ton of different and outdated solutions to this.

For context I'm okay with these files being viewed by anyone, I do not want any users to be prompted to sign in to view the excel files (scope = anonymous). Right now I can embed this into my web app if I manually go to file settings from the file and click embed and then copy the embed code. The embed code is not much different from the share link URL it just has a sourcedoc argument that I'm not sure how to find.

However when I do it this way the user gets prompted to sign in from the manually grabbed embed code to the Excel doc, I do not want this.

So how can I make my excel docs public and embed them in my website, I plan to index all these links programmatically. Currently I'm using R and the Microsoft365R package which interacts with the Azure Graph API. Below is some code, but this is just a wrapper for the graph API so anything that works on the Graph API I should be able to figure out in this R package.

```
library(Microsoft365R)
library(openxlsx)

# successfully connects to one drive
odb <- get_business_onedrive()

# successfully uploads dummy file
odb$upload_file(
    src = "data/iris.xlsx",
    dest = "public/iris.xlsx"
)

# successfully lists dummy file 
files <- odb$list_files(   
    path = "public" 
)

# grabs the dummy file 
file <- odb$get_item(   
    itemid = files$id[1]
)  

# successfully creates a share link but cannot be embedded or I'm missing something 
file$create_share_link(   
    type = "view",   
    expiry = NULL,   
    scope = "anonymous" 
)  

# fails to create share link, which appears to not be available for business one drive accounts 
file$create_share_link(   
    type = "embed",
    expiry = NULL 
)
  
# opens the existing file for me to view 
odb$open_item(  
     itemid = files$id[1] 
)
```

How can I find the URL I need programmatically and iterate over many files to make them all embeddable / public, if I can just be shown what I need to do for one file I can handle the rest.

Some more details on this github issue too [here](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R/issues/182)

Thanks!